# How to save a texture2D as a jpeg to a file

Tags: c#, xna

I'm attempting to draw many textures onto one texture to create a map for an RTS game, and while I can can draw an individual texture onscreen, drawing them all to a render target seems to have no effect (the window remains AliceBlue when debugging) . I am trying to determine whether or not anything is even drawn to the render target, and so I am trying to save it as a Jpeg to a file and then view that Jpeg, from my desktop. How can I access that Jpeg from MemoryStream?

protected override void LoadContent()
        {

```
         spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
         gridImage = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1000, 1000);
         GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(gridImage);
         GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);
         spriteBatch.Begin();


         foreach (tile t in grid.tiles)
         {
             Texture2D dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>(t.texture);
             spriteBatch.Draw(dirt, t.getVector2(), Color.White);
         }
         test = Content.Load<Texture2D>("dirt");


             GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
             MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            gridImage.SaveAsJpeg(memoryStream, gridImage.Width, gridImage.Height); //Or SaveAsPng( memoryStream, texture.Width, texture.Height )



         //    rt.Dispose();
             spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Comment: @Skami You should not [add redundant tags to questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99072/should-adding-redundant-but-related-tags-be-encouraged-or-discouraged). You have made [over 200 tiny edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits) today, of which most did not really contribute to the quality of the site.

Comment: @Lucius Sorry, I will read the rules more thoroughly and make sure I won't mess up again.

Comment: @Skami I am sure you did it with the best of intentions. Just keep in mind, that everytime you make such an edit at least 3 moderators have to deal with it and the question gets bumped. Also, XNA doesn't necessarily mean C#. XNA works theoretically for any .NET language, and pratically at least for C# *and* VB.

Comment: @Lucius That's the reason why I added C# to the questions that were asking for C# and not to every random question I was simply trying to make it easier to find questions that asked for a specific language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a simple screenshot method,

```
  void Screenie()
            {
                int width = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
                int height = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

                //Force a frame to be drawn (otherwise back buffer is empty) 
                Draw(new GameTime());

                //Pull the picture from the buffer 
                int[] backBuffer = new int[width * height];
                GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData(backBuffer);

                //Copy to texture
                Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height, false, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat);
                texture.SetData(backBuffer);
                //Get a date for file name
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now; //Get the date for the file name
                Stream stream = File.Create(SCREENSHOT FOLDER + date.ToString("MM-dd-yy H;mm;ss") + ".png"); 

                //Save as PNG
                texture.SaveAsPng(stream, width, height);
                stream.Dispose();
                texture.Dispose();
            }
```

Also, Are you loading   `Texture2D dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>(t.texture);` Every frame? It looks like it... Dont do that! That will cause massive lag loading hundreds of tiles, hundreds of times per second! instead make a global texture `Texture2D DirtDexture` and in your `LoadContent()` method do `DirtTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(t.texture);`  Now when you draw you can do `spriteBatch.Draw(DirtTexture,...`

Do the same with `spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);` and
  `gridImage = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1000, 1000);`

You dont need to make new RenderTarget and Spritebatch each frame! Just do it in the `Initialize()` Method!

Also see [RenderTarget2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget2d.aspx) and [XNA RenderTarget Sample](http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2011/02/18/xna-rendertarget2d-sample.aspx) For more information on using render targets

EDIT: I realize its all in LoadContent, I didnt see that because the formatting was messed up, remember to add your Foreach (Tile, etc) in your Draw Method

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I was drawing all these tiles to a render target precisely so I could avoid drawing them all each frame: I just want to draw them once onto a big bitmap, and then just draw that bitmap. I found this screenshot method useful because it showed me how a Stream works. If I wanted to save my image to my desktop, I would just change SCREENSHOT FOLDER to some other path name, right?

Comment: Correct, It will save it in the folder you specify with the currrent date/time as the filename.